# Powershell Preferred method to remove the file older than x days

Tags: powershell

I see below two methods doing the same operation in Power Shell, which is preferred method to remove the file older than 1 day?

**Option 1:**

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp -File | ?{($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)) -and ($_.Name -like "a*") -and ($_.Extension -eq ".csv")} | Select-Object –ExpandProperty FullName | %{Remove-Item $_ -Force -WhatIf}
```

**Option 2**

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp -Filter "a*.csv" -File | Where LastWriteTime -lt  (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)  | Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
```

Thanks

SR

Comment: @PaulG good point, I updated both to last write time.

Comment: My personal preferrence would be option 2 because of readability and length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with Option 2 because you *always* want to filter before continuing with the pipeline. Dealing with less data ahead of time in pipelines will always be better.

Option 1 will get *every* file object (e.g. 100's of files) to pass down the pipeline before it can begin to look at applying the where clause.

Option 2 will filter `"a*.csv"` files, which should always get you fewer files (e.g. 10's), before continuing down the pipeline to apply the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

Option 2.

`?` and `where` are aliases for the `where-object` cmdlet. filtering aside, they both are checking if the LastWriteTime is older then 24hours in the same way.

As stated by [HAL9256](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2150063/hal9256) if you need to filter, you should do that first.

If you need more fancy filtering (e.g. regex ), filtering with `where-object` is the next best thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way.

```
get-childitem | where { (get-date) - $_.lastwritetime -gt '1' } | remove-item -whatif
```